# Omitting parameter with default value in a subclass function override

Tags: c++

I am writing an interface for several I/O classes.

There is a function that looks for information in different kinds of files (sometimes html, sdb, txt, ...):

```
bool Search(std::string file, std::string field)
```

However, one of these requires an additional parameter to complement the SQL query. In this case the sdb needs to specify in what table the field is located.

I am trying something like the following (it does not compile, I am aware):

```
class fileIO{
  public:
    virtual ~FileIO(){};
    virtual bool Search(std::string file, std::string field,
                          std::string additional = 0 /* for sdb only */) = 0;
}
class readHTML : fileIO{
  public:
    bool Search(std::string file, std::string field); //does NOT override virtual method
```

1. Is there anything that can give me the behavior I am looking for?
2. Is such strategy according to C++ standards?
3. What else could I add to replace such enforcement on the interface?

I am sorry if the title is misleading, I am looking for an alternative with that behavior. I could not find it so far.

Comment: You should override the function with an identical signature. The `readHTML` function is completely different as far as signature is concerned. If it makes your code ugly or annoying then you need to re-think how your base `Search` method is declared.

Comment: You can use `std::optional<std::string>`.

Comment: Tip: Use `const std::string&` as the default type for string arguments. This avoids copies and accidental alterations.

Comment: So all the classes that do not use that parameter should carry it as a placeholder. I can do that. Could you tell me if that is a good strategy? In your opinion is it better to leave it out the Interface? @tadman

Comment: I'd take a closer look at what the `additional` argument does. You might want to define two functions, like `Search` and `SearchAdd` where the second has that argument and the first does not. The subclasses can override whatever method(s) are applicable.

Comment: @tadman I am using it with std::move() on the call side. I will consider that

Comment: You really shouldn't need to use `std::move` to call a function. That's way too much work. References, especially const references, do this basically for free.

Comment: @Eljay Thank you for the insight. I was looking into it and may leave a note for update once available for the codebase!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it, I'd say.

At the caller site, there is only two possibilities: you know your specific `fileIO` instance is a `sdbIO` or you don't. If you do, you can call an overloaded version of `Search` defined in `sdbIO` which takes this additional info. If you don't, you don't and `sdbIO::Search` should be defined in terms of its overloaded version.

```
struct fileIO
{
    virtual bool Search(std::string file, std::string field) = 0;
}

struct sdbIO : fileIO
{
    bool Search(std::string file, std::string field, std::string additional);
    bool Search(std::string file, std::string field) override
    {
        Search(file, field, "");
    }
};
```

At the caller site:

```
void f(fileIO& io)
{
    // I know this is a sdb:
    dynamic_cast<sdbIO&>(io).Search("/file", "text", "WHERE answer=42");

    // I don't
    io.Search("/file", "text");
}
```

---

notes: do you really need a copy of those strings?

Comment: This makes sense. I currently have everything outside this abstract class and wanted to put it into a more organized fashion. I was looking more to restrict than to give it functionality, so I "zoned out" this possibility. You are correct in presume the caller knows it is an sdb, so if that class is called through `Search(str,str)` I should throw an error (if the user could do it - it can, it is from a gherkin file). Thank you

Comment: Note that the design you are describing (throw error when calling the wrong method) violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If, given a `fileIO`, I need to care whether it has a certain dynamic type to use it correctly, it is really not fulfilling the interface. One way around it would be to require the `additional` to be set (and stored) in `sdbIO` before calling `Search(a, b)` (and `sdbIO` will tack on the `additional`) but maybe that doesn't make sense. Overall, think hard again if `Search` should really be in the interface.

Comment: Hi @MaxLanghof. I described it very poorly. I meant that the overload being called will just return false. I actually realized both overloads are needed by the interface - even though only one will be used. Thanks for the reference to that principle, I never heard of that and will check it

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the virtual function in the non-public interface and make the public interface (with the default argument) non-virtual.

```
struct Interface
{
     ...
     // public interface calls the abstract members.
     bool Search(string const&a, string const&b, string const&c = "") 
     {
         if(c.empty() && need_third_string())
             throw runtime_error("search requires an additional string argument");
         return search(a,b,c);
     }
   protected:
     virtual bool need_third_string() const = 0;
     virtual bool search(string const&, string const&, string const&) const=0;
};
```

with obvious derivations:

```
struct A : Interface
{
  protected:
    bool need_third_string() const override
    { return false; }
    bool search(string const&a, string const&b, string const&) const override
    { /* search ignoring third argument */ }
};

struct B : Interface
{
  protected:
    bool need_third_string() const override
    { return true; }
    bool search(string const&a, string const&b, string const&c) const override
    { /* search ignoring using all 3 arguments */ }
};
```

Comment: I am trying this at this moment. Could you explain me how is the (non-virtual) public version of Search working? I presume I should override that in the child classes.

Comment: @MTLaurentys No, `Interface::Search()` simply calls `interface::search()`, which is pure virtual.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with above two way to handle things. Still, I have just one more.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;
typedef struct
{
    std::string arg1;
    std::string arg2;
    std::string arg3;
} Param;

class FileIO{
  public:
    virtual ~FileIO(){};
    virtual void Search(Param param) = 0;
};
class ReadHTML : public FileIO{
  public:
    void Search(Param param)
    {
        if(param.arg3.length() > 0) // Some logic to handle things here.
            search3(param.arg1, param.arg2, param.arg3);
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("Bad call with param");
    }

    private:
    void search3(std::string arg1, std::string arg2, std::string arg3)
    {
        std::cout << " I am called with Html::Search3" << std::endl;
    }
};
class ReadTxt : public FileIO{
  public:
    void Search(Param param)
    {
        if(param.arg1.length() && param.arg2.length()) // Some logic to handle things here.
            search2(param.arg1, param.arg2);
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("Bad call with param");
    }

    private:
    void search2(std::string arg1, std::string arg2)
    {
        std::cout << " I am called with Txt::Search2" << std::endl;
    }
};

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    FileIO *io = new ReadHTML();  
    Param  paramHtml = {"a", "b", "c"};
    io->Search(paramHtml); // Put some try .. catch 
    Param  paramTxt = {"a", "b"};
    io = new ReadTxt(); // Put some try...catch
    io->Search(paramTxt);
    return 0;
}
```